# fbAsyncInit doesn't work in dynamic content

Tags: javascript, facebook, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have this code (from FB developer doc)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        channelUrl: 'xxxxxxx',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange',function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //FB.login();
        } else {
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
```

the code above is in index.html and i am loading index.html dynamically through ajax call.

the problem i am facing is `fbAsyncInit` is not fired when index.html is loaded dynamically.

any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How are you calling index.html and what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Shadowfax i am using jQuery.ajax to load the index.html to a div. i got no errors. the sdk fails silently :(

Comment: This isnt possible, can you demonstrate.. Or add more code